# Get Area size using Dragbox in Openlayers 3

Tags: polygon, openlayers, area

I need to be able to show the square meters of an area using dragbox.  There's a great example using [draw polygon](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/measure.html?q=measure), but I need to limit users to a regular rectangle.

The formulas and SHOULD be the same or simular. I've replaced "Draw" with "DragBox" and "drawstart" and "drawend" with "boxstart" and "boxend".  I also commented out the "formatLength" function, as I don't need it.

I'd use this script if I knew how to limit draw polygon to a regular rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a week of trial and error, I figured it out for myself... again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
    var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({
        altShiftDragRotate: false,
        pinchRotate: false
    });
    var measureTooltipEiement;
    var draw;
    var measureTooltip;
    var pointerMoveHandler = function (evt) {
        if (evt instanceof ol.interaction.DragBox) {
            return;
        }

        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
        if (draw) {
            var output;
            var geom = (draw.getGeometry());
            if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                output = formatArea(/** @type {ol.geom.Polygon} */ (geom));
            }
            tooltipCoord = geom.getlnteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
            measureTooltipEiement.innerHTML = output;
            measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
        }
    };

    var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': 'ne:NE1_HR_LC_SR_W_DR'
                }
            })
        })
    ];
    var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.ScaleLine({
                units: 'degrees'
            })
        ]),
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
    // map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);
    var drawBox;
    var aoiFeature = new ol.Feature();
    var area;
    // Use a ol.FeatureOverlay to store the AOI
    var aoiFeatureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay(aoiFeature);
    var aoiStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'cyan',
            width: 5
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(O, 255, 255, 0.3)'
        })
    });
    aoiFeatureOverlay.setStyle(aoiStyle);
    // A Drag Box interaction used to pass the geometry to the aoiFeatureOverlay
    draw = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
        condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
        type: 'Polygon',
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(O, 0, 0 , 0.5)',
                lineDash: [10, 10],
                width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(O , 0, 0 , 0 .7)'
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0 .2)'
                })
            })
        })
    });

    map.addlnteraction(draw);

    createMeasureTooltip();

    draw.on('boxstart', function () {
        map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);
        map.removeOverlay(drawBox);
    }, this);

    draw.on('boxend', function (evt) {
        $('. tooltip-static').remove();
        if (aoiFeatureOverlay.getFeatures().getArray().length >= 1) {
            aoiFeatureOverlay.removeFeature(aoiFeature);
        }
        var geomBox = evt.target.getGeometry();
        geom = draw.getGeometry();
        var featureS = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: geomBox
        });
        drawBox = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
            map: map,
            features: [featureS]
        });

    map.addOverlay(drawBox);

    }, this);

    function createMeasureTooltip() {
        if (measureTooltipEiement) {
            measureTooltipEiement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipEiement);
        }
    }

    measureTooltipEiement = document.createEiement('div');

    measureTooltipEiement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';

    measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
        element: measureTooltipEiement,
        offset: [0, -15],
        positioning: 'bottom-center'
    });

    map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);

    var formatArea = function (polygon) {
        var sourceProj = map.getView().getProjection();
        var geom = /** @type {o l.geom.Polygon} */(polygon.clone().transform(
                sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326'));
        var coordinates = geom.getlinearRing(O).getCoordinates();
        area = Math.abs(wgs84Sphere.geodesicArea(coordinates));
        var output;
        if (area > 10000) {
            output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
                    ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
        } else {
            output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
                    ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
        }
        return output;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to have similar functionality.  See the following JSfiddle.  You can adjust the math portion according to your needs.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melbsurfer/bunkfaLs/7/)

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  I actually knew how to get the area on boxend....  What I need is to see the sq area while it's being drawn using the tooltip function.

Comment: Just for general knowledge, using the ALT key as a modifier is a bad practice, as in most of the Unix systems, it drags the current window.